# How can I relate two generic struct fields in rust?

Tags: generics, rust, types

I have some JSON being parsed. It is structured like:

```
{
  elements: [{
    t: "USER",
    value: { username: "foo", age: 18 },
  },
  {
    t: "KEYBOARD",
    value: { switches: "BLUE", price: 150 }
  }]
}
```

I want to have some rust struct that lets me express the type of `value` with respect to `t`.

The amount of values for `T` is known and fixed.

In short: Is there a way to have a rust struct such that:

```rs
struct Element<T> {
  t: T,
  value: SomeNewTypeDependentOn<T>
}
```

In TypeScript this is possible with `T extends "USER" ? UserObj : T extends "KEYBOARD" ? KeyboardObj ...`, but is this possible in Rust?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid JSON (keys must be quoted). Also, trailing comma is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use serde's [adjacently-tagged enums](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#adjacently-tagged):

```rust
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE")]
#[serde(tag = "t", content = "value")]
pub enum Elements {
    User { username: String, age: u32 },
    Keyboard { switches: String, price: u32 },
}
```